# Computed value not display until I click component in Vue Devtools

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2, vue-component

I have problems with my computed value. If I add item to cart, the `totalPrice` will remain 0, until I click the component in Vue Devtools, it will display the value. However, the `Item Count` working normally. Why is that happening? :/

```
data() {
    return {
      totalPrice: 0,
    };
  },

computed: {
    calcTotal() {
        this.cart.forEach((item) => {
            this.totalPrice += item.price * item.quantity
        });
        return this.totalPrice;
    }
  }
```

I am using it to display the total price for whole cart.

```
<div>
  <table class="table">
    <tr v-show="cart.length > 0">
      <td>Item count ({{this.cart.length}})</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><b>Net Payable</b></td>
      <td>{{ totalPrice }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do **not** mutate your `data` properties inside a computed property. It's a great way to end up in an infinite loop. They should be as close to pure functions as possible.

`totalPrice` should be your computed property that *reduces* the `cart` items to a number (the sum of `price * quantity`)

```js
// Adjust locale and currency code accordingly
const currencyFormatter = Intl.NumberFormat("en", { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' })

export default {
  data: () => ({
    cart: []
  }),
  filters: {
    currency: (value) => currencyFormatter.format(value)
  },
  computed: {
    totalPrice: ({ cart }) =>
      cart.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price * item.quantity, 0)
  }
}
```

```html
<td>{{ totalPrice | currency }}</td>
```

See also ~ [Filters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html)

Comment: Hi @Phil,  is this applicable if my `cart: [ ]` in `data ( )` ?

Comment: @cdogol I've update my answer. Next time, please include relevant information in your question

Comment: Sorry about that, and thank you for your answer! I am new to vuejs, didn't know it could work this way too. Thank you again! :)